# CommonsCSV not parsing anything

Tags: java, csv

I'm having trouble parsing a CSV file (actually Tab Seperated) with Apache Commons CSV.
It parses neither the headers, nor the records.
getCurrentLineNumber() and getRecordNumber() return 0.

It is the correct file as shown by getCanonicalPath().
It can be read and written (Tested with canRead(), canWrite())
It is valid CSV (No " at all, columns are cleanly seperated with a \t, empty columns are empty, I hope I took care of the äÜöß special chars with the encoding, ...)

```
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println(file.canExecute() + ":" + file.canRead() + ":" + file.canWrite());
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(file, Charset.forName("ISO_8859_1"), CSVFormat.TDF);
if(parser.isClosed())
    System.out.println("is closed");
System.out.println(parser.getCurrentLineNumber() + "\t" + 
    parser.getRecordNumber() + "\t" + parser.getRecords());
Map<String, Integer> headers = parser.getHeaderMap();
if(headers.containsKey(ALREADY_PRINTED_COLUMN))
     return;
```

(Yes I left all my poor man's debugging code there).

The output is this:

> C:\Users\5.7.2012\Documents\ADRESSE_1.TXT
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   true:true:true
>   0   0   []

I can't step into the parser as I use the library (as a matter of fact I'm not required to use that library).

For reference this is (slightly modified as the actual data is sensitive) example data

> Nummer    Name    Adresszusatz    Strasse Land    PLZ Ort Telefon Telefon2    Fax EMail   Adressanrede    Anrede  Typ Geburtsdatum    ...
>   294 Name Familyname     Main-street. 44 D   11111   Some City   00000 / 0 00 00             Frau    Sehr geehrte Frau Familyname    Patient 00.00.0000  ...
>   396 Name-Secondname Familyname      Fourth-street 5 D   00000   Same City   00000 / 00 00               Herrn   Sehr geehrter Herr Familyname   Patient 00.00.0000  ...

Comment: There's a suspicious `NullPointerException` in your output: I'd start there.

Comment: @BartKiers well yes and that is because headers == null. But that actually is my question, why does the CSV doesn't get parsed (which leads to it not having a header and so the `NullPointerException`)